# Print Chart within <div> tag

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, printing, charts

I'm trying to print the content from a Div tag, I have a Grid and a Chart but it only prints the Grid, the Chart is blank, this is the code I'm using:

```
<input id="btnprint" type="button" onclick="PrintDiv()" value="Print" /></center>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('Content');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1400,height=800,location=no,left=200px');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Debug in firebug and see the value of `divToPrint.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the onload function. Works for me. Maybe your ID isn't correctly spelled.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it keeps showing only the Grid, the ID is correct because the Grid is showing but the Chart doesn't, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I did it adding this to the web.config in the appsetings:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" ...deleteAfterServicing=false;"/>
```